# Linux: Can I safely delete /sys/keynal/debug/hid folders?

Tags: linux, backup, filesystems, linux-mint

I use Linux Mint's *Backup Tool*
to make a backup of my all disk.

During backup process, the tool freezes very often when checking (before copying) **/sys/keynal/debug/hid/0003:413C:2106.0001/events**
Can I simply delete such files ? There is 2 folder like "0003...", and such files seems useless to backup.
Freeze ? It freezes while backing-up (*after* the calculation pre-process), precisely when calculating the sha1sum signature.

Can I safely delete /sys/keynal/debug/hid folders ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an option to bypass this folder from the backup app?

The `/sys/kernel` folder is created by kernel/device drivers dynamically and you don't need to back up them. If you're still having problem with the `/sys/kernel/debug/hid` folder, try to umount the `/sys/kernel/debug` folder temporally.

```
umount /sys/kernel/debug
```

and mount it back after backing up(or reboot the machine)

```
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
```

Comment: "The /sys/kernel folder is created by kernel/device drivers dynamically and you don't need to back up them. I" @Chris.C . Thank you--